# Debugging Xamarin Android apps if I'm using VSTS hosted builds / HockeyApp

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, azure-devops, hockeyapp

I have been developing a Xamarin Android app using Visual Studio Community 2015. So far, everything has been working well for debugging, as I simply build my app in VS, and connect my phone to my laptop and debug it using F5.

Recently, I started using HockeyApp for crash reporting, so that as I'm using my app (during the day when I'm not programming), if it crashes, I can send crash reports. This works OK, but the crash reports don't include line numbers, and also I don't have good references to what build of the app crashed, as the app itself isn't actually getting uploaded to HockeyApp, nor are the debugging symbols.

To help with this, I'm trying to get more organized using Visual Studio Team Services, doing hosted builds upon checkin of my source code, and automatically uploading the app and debugging symbols to HockeyApp.

Now I'm trying to reconcile in my mind how this is supposed to all work for me. If I'm coding in VS and debugging through VS, the app is getting deployed to my phone. But now, I check in the source code, and VSTS does a CI build and uploads everything to HockeyApp. But now, the CI build that VSTS did isn't really the same build that's on my phone, since that build came from the Visual Studio build.

So, when I'm done coding then later in the day, I run my app and it crashes, I'm concerned that the crash report from HockeyApp isn't actually going to relate to what Hockeyapp has. For one, I may not have done a check-in to the source control, in which case, my phone will have a newer version than HockeyApp has. But even if I had remembered to check it in, it's really not the same "build" (since my phone has the APK that was built by Visual Studio and HockeyApp has the APK that was built by VSTS).

Questions:

1) Is there a way to upload my app and debug symbols directly from Visual Studio, without going through a VSTS build? (preferrably automatically upon every build, so that I don't have to remember to do an extra step)?

2) If not, what are the best practices to resolve the issues that I mentioned above?

Ideally, I don't want to have to do any extra steps when I'm done coding for the day. I want to be able to always know that the last version that I built and deployed to my phone will have been uploaded to HockeyApp, so that if it crashes, the crash repo that HockeyApp sends will match with the correct source code and debug symbols.

Comment: For  UWP application, we could upload symbols using the VS: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application, but for Android build, it really uses the VSTS/TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, This depends on the project you working on. If you are working on a UWP project, there is an "Enable Crash Analytics" option and "Distribute With Hockey App" option allow you to do this when you right click on the project. But if you are working on a Xamarin.Android project, there is no option to do this. You need to upload them to Hockey App manually. However, you can create a power-shell script to upload these files to Hockey App and configure this power-shell script as post-build event. You can check the power-shell script here for reference: [upload_file.ps](https://gist.github.com/ashtom/6395b9d8b6a693b3fa26).

And for the Visual Studio Team Services(VSTS) build, you just need to make sure that the app version and build configuration is totally the same as you debugging through VS from your local machine. Hockey App will detect the version automatically and send the data to the related build version.